# How can I add a featureLayer style for administrative area level 1 in React using react-google-maps/api and Google Maps API?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, next.js, google-maps-api-3

I'm currently working on a Next.js project where I want to color up to **administrative_area_level_1** boundaries on a Google Map using the react-google-maps/api library.

However, I'm having trouble finding the appropriate method to add a featureLayer style specifically for administrative area level 1. Basically I want to **style a boundary polygon** from this [Google Maps documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/dds-boundaries/style-polygon) .

I've implemented the map in this component `ShowMap.tsx`. This component can render the map. But I can't add the function so that when I select a location, for example, MIT, The whole area of Boston doesn't fill up with color.

Now, I'm here banging my head for 4 days on stop and asking for your help.

Could anyone please guide me on how to add a featureLayer style specifically for administrative area level 1 using react-google-maps/api? Any help or code examples would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

## What I've tried

I've tried their documentation, but it only has code for pure html js application, which as you've guessed it, doesn't work when I try their examples. I've also tried their official youtube video tutorial, which also dosen't work for me :) . [Tutorial with timestamp](https://youtu.be/br-ZiLYKaI0?t=911)

I have gone through the official Google Maps documentation, but all the examples provided there demonstrate the usage of the featureLayer style within the initMap function, not within the GoogleMap component of the react-google-maps/api library.

This is the `ShowMap.tsx` component.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";
import SearchComponent from "./SearchComponent";

let map: google.maps.Map;
//@ts-ignore
let featureLayer;

const center = { lat: 23.685, lng: 90.3563 };

async function initMap() {
  const { Map } = (await google.maps.importLibrary(
    "maps"
  )) as google.maps.MapsLibrary;

  map = new Map(document.getElementById("map") as HTMLElement, {
    center: center,
    zoom: 10,
    mapId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MAP_ID,
  });

  //@ts-ignore
  featureLayer = map.getFeatureLayer("ADMINISTRATIVE_AREA_LEVEL_1");
  // featureLayer = map.getFeatureLayer('LOCALITY');
}

export default function ShowMap({ showPin }: { showPin: boolean }) {
  const [dhukse, setDhukse] = useState(true);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!window.google) {
      const script = document.createElement("script");
      script.src = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY}`;
      script.onload = () => {
        initMap();
      };
      document.head.appendChild(script);

      return () => {
        document.head.removeChild(script);
      };
    } else {
      initMap();
    }
  }, [center]);

  const handleSearch = (
    place: google.maps.places.PlaceResult,
    placeId: string
  ) => {
    if (featureLayer && map) {
      const featureStyleOptions: google.maps.Data.StyleOptions = {
        fillColor: "#ff7859",
        fillOpacity: 1,
        strokeColor: "#ff7859",
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeWeight: 3.0,
      };

      featureLayer.style = (options: { feature: { placeId: string } }) => {
        // console.log('dhukse')
        console.log(options.feature, placeId);
        if (options.feature.placeId === placeId) {
          console.log("vitore dhukse");
          return featureStyleOptions;
        }
      };

      if (place.geometry && place.geometry.location) {
        const lat = place.geometry.location.lat();
        const lng = place.geometry.location.lng();
        console.log(lat, lng);
        if (typeof lat === "number" && typeof lng === "number") {
          map.setZoom(12);
          map.setCenter({ lat, lng });
          setTimeout(() => {
            map.setZoom(8);
          }, 3000);
        }
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <SearchComponent onSearch={handleSearch} />
      <div id="map" style={{ width: "100%", height: "700px" }}></div>
    </>
  );
}
```

I have set up a map with these styles enabled:
Javascript, Vector Map

I also have enabled the feature layers:

[Feature Layers enabled for my map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9gGEl.png)

Comment: Have you tried your map id with a standard HTML / JS snippet? Does it work as you expect?

Comment: I tried one from their official examples, a pure html/ts project. It's even weirder! It works, only for the LOCALITY layer. Not anything else. This is the [example](https://stackblitz.com/github/googlemaps/js-samples/tree/sample-boundaries-simple?file=README.md) I ran.

However, I need the nextjs implementation. Also found out, there's some issues with chrome! Chrome can't render, but firefox can! If you can't see the example on [Google Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/dds-boundaries/style-polygon) , try Firefox.

Comment: Both examples work fine, on Chrome (up to date). Your Stackblitz just makes use of an API key that is not properly restricted for that website. If I use a non restricted API key, it works fine on my end.

Comment: got it working. chrome issue is still a bug. but the actual problem is  Apparently you can't color ADMINISTRATIVE AREA if you select New york, because it's a locality... So, you have to get a place first, then get the country (USA in this case), then color everything 

I'll post an answer to this question later

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please see [Google Boundaries Coverage](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/dds-boundaries/coverage) to see if your region supports the Administrative Area.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But the issue isn't with Boundary coverage. It's something related to loading the maps.

Comment: Added an answer that works. But misses out for locations under POSTAL CODE area. Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

## This isn't the best solution. So, please add your answers as well so that I can imporve my code. Thanks :)

### How I solved it

Make sure you have set up these from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/dds-boundaries/style-polygon) before starting:

- Map Id for JavaScript Vector map
- All the feature layers enabled in your map style.

1. I made a query to get the `placeId` of a location. This query is done in a searchbox component. Where I'm using the places api to get the placeId from the predictions. However, its not important. You just need the `placeId`. Then, I passed the placeId to the `ShowMap.tsx` component.

```
const handleFormSubmit = (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (predictions.length > 0 && selectedIndex >= 0) {
      const placeId = predictions[selectedIndex].place_id;
      const placesService = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(
        document.createElement("div")
      );
      placesService.getDetails(
        { placeId: placeId, fields: ["geometry"] },
        (place) => {
          if (place) {
            handleCountrySearch(place);
            onSearch(place, placeId, country);
            setSearchQuery("");
            setPredictions([]);
            setSelectedIndex(-1);
          }
        }
      );
    }
  };
```

2. I made a function to implement the `featureLayer`. It's straight from the documentation. I'm just passing the `placeId` dynamically as the user selects a prediction.

```
  const colorFeatureLayer = (placeId: string, featureLayerName: string) => {
      //@ts-ignore
      const featureLayer = mapRef.current?.getFeatureLayer(featureLayerName);
      // Define a style with Crafteur Orange fill and border.
      //@ts-ignore
      const featureStyleOptions: google.maps.FeatureStyleOptions = {
        strokeColor: "#ff7859",
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeWeight: 3.0,
        fillColor: "#ff7859",
        fillOpacity: 1.0,
      };

      // Apply the style to a single boundary.
      //@ts-ignore
      featureLayer.style = (options: { feature: { placeId: string } }) => {
        if (options.feature.placeId == placeId) {
          return featureStyleOptions;
        }
      };
    };
```

3. 

> This is important. Found out the hard way

So, you have to understand what data is sent as a response for the place id. This is a response from a result of a places query for `New York, NY, USA`.

```
{
    "description": "New York, NY, USA",
    "matched_substrings": [
        {
            "length": 3,
            "offset": 0
        }
    ],
    "place_id": "ChIJOwg_06VPwokRYv534QaPC8g",
    "reference": "ChIJOwg_06VPwokRYv534QaPC8g",
    "structured_formatting": {
        "main_text": "New York",
        "main_text_matched_substrings": [
            {
                "length": 3,
                "offset": 0
            }
        ],
        "secondary_text": "NY, USA"
    },
    "terms": [
        {
            "offset": 0,
            "value": "New York"
        },
        {
            "offset": 10,
            "value": "NY"
        },
        {
            "offset": 14,
            "value": "USA"
        }
    ],
    "types": [
        "locality",
        "political",
        "geocode"
    ]
}
```

Notice this part:

```
   "types": [
        "locality",
        "political",
        "geocode"
    ]
```

As it turns out, **your feature layer will not be colored** if the `place_id` does not contain the `type`. For example, if I want to color till ADMINISTRATIVE_AREA_LEVEL_1 for New York, you can't do that! Because, New York doesn't have the type `locality` in its `placeId`.

So, be sure to check the placeid contains the expected feature layer.

4. To solve this issue of a placeid not containing the exact type, I just made a the call to `colorFeatureLayer` function 3 times with different featureLayers.

```
 const handleSearch = (
    result: google.maps.places.PlaceResult,
    placeId: string,
    country: string
  ) => {
    console.log(" ~ file: ShowMap.tsx:73 ~ country:\n", country);
    showPin && setSelectedPin(null);
    console.log(placeId);
    const location = result.geometry?.location;

    if (location) {
      const newPosition = { lat: location.lat(), lng: location.lng() };
      console.log(newPosition);

      setSelectedState((prev: any) => {
        return [...prev, newPosition];
      });
      const bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
      bounds.extend(newPosition);
      // setOptionsStyles(styles);
      if (markerRef.current) {
        const marker = markerRef.current;
        const currentPosition = marker.getPosition();
        // setOptionsStyles(styles);
        if (currentPosition) {
          bounds.extend(currentPosition);
        }

        marker.setPosition(newPosition);
        marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.DROP);
      } else {
        setSelectedPin(newPosition);
        // setOptionsStyles(styles);
        markerRef.current = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: newPosition,
          animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
          map: mapRef.current,
        });
      }
      colorFeatureLayer(placeId, "LOCALITY");
      colorFeatureLayer(placeId, "ADMINISTRATIVE_AREA_LEVEL_1");
      colorFeatureLayer(placeId, "COUNTRY");

      setOriginalZoom(8);
      setMapCenter(newPosition);
      mapRef.current?.fitBounds(bounds);
      setTimeout(() => {
        setOriginalZoom(8);
        zoomOut();
      }, 3000);
    }
  };
```

It's a bit of a hack because it has some bugs. For example, it misses if I choose some location like Times Square, which doesn't include any feature layer I've implemented. This documentation page ([Use Places APIs and Geocoding with data-driven styling for boundaries](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/dds-boundaries/dds-use-maps-places-apis)) shows some better alternative approaches, but I wasn't able to implement it properly.

## Results

As I've added 3 calls to color the feature layer, I can color if the location has these following types:
`LOCALITY`, `ADMINISTRATIVE_AREA_LEVEL_1`, `COUNTRY`

[Example image of New York feature layer being colored](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0NtTJ.png)

## Complete Code for `ShowMap.tsx`

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import { GoogleMap, useLoadScript, Marker } from "@react-google-maps/api";
import SearchComponent from "./SearchComponent";
import { Jelly } from "@uiball/loaders";

const libraries: (
  | "geometry"
  | "places"
  | "drawing"
  | "localContext"
  | "visualization"
)[] = ["places"];

const mapContainerStyle: React.CSSProperties = {
  width: "100%",
  height: "630px",
};

const center = {
  lat: 20.773,
  lng: -156.01,
};

const ShowMap = ({
  showPin,
  updateFormData,
  selectedState,
  setSelectedState,
}: any) => {
  const { isLoaded, loadError } = useLoadScript({
    googleMapsApiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY!,
    libraries,
  });

  const [selectedPin, setSelectedPin] = useState<{
    lat: number;
    lng: number;
  } | null>(null);
  const [mapCenter, setMapCenter] = useState(center);
  const [originalZoom, setOriginalZoom] = useState(8);
  const mapRef = useRef<google.maps.Map | null>(null);
  const markerRef = useRef<google.maps.Marker | null>(null);

  const zoomOut = () => {
    setOriginalZoom(7);
  };

  const handleMapClick = (event: google.maps.MapMouseEvent) => {
    if (!event.latLng) {
      return;
    }

    const pinPosition = {
      lat: event.latLng.lat(),
      lng: event.latLng.lng(),
    };
    setSelectedPin(pinPosition);
    console.log("Selected pin position:", pinPosition);
    if (markerRef.current) {
      const marker = markerRef.current;
      marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
      setTimeout(() => {
        marker.setAnimation(null);
      }, 2000);
    }
  };

  const handleSearch = (
    result: google.maps.places.PlaceResult,
    placeId: string,
    country: string
  ) => {
    console.log(" ~ file: ShowMap.tsx:73 ~ country:\n", country);
    showPin && setSelectedPin(null);
    console.log(placeId);
    const location = result.geometry?.location;

    if (location) {
      const newPosition = { lat: location.lat(), lng: location.lng() };
      console.log(newPosition);

      setSelectedState((prev: any) => {
        return [...prev, newPosition];
      });
      const bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
      bounds.extend(newPosition);
      // setOptionsStyles(styles);
      if (markerRef.current) {
        const marker = markerRef.current;
        const currentPosition = marker.getPosition();
        // setOptionsStyles(styles);
        if (currentPosition) {
          bounds.extend(currentPosition);
        }

        marker.setPosition(newPosition);
        marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.DROP);
      } else {
        setSelectedPin(newPosition);
        // setOptionsStyles(styles);
        markerRef.current = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: newPosition,
          animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
          map: mapRef.current,
        });
      }
      colorFeatureLayer(placeId, "LOCALITY");
      colorFeatureLayer(placeId, "ADMINISTRATIVE_AREA_LEVEL_1");
      colorFeatureLayer(placeId, "COUNTRY");

      setOriginalZoom(8);
      setMapCenter(newPosition);
      mapRef.current?.fitBounds(bounds);
      setTimeout(() => {
        setOriginalZoom(8);
        zoomOut();
      }, 3000);
    }
  };

 
    const colorFeatureLayer = (placeId: string, featureLayerName: string) => {
      //@ts-ignore
      const featureLayer = mapRef.current?.getFeatureLayer(featureLayerName);
      // Define a style with Crafteur Orange fill and border.
      //@ts-ignore
      const featureStyleOptions: google.maps.FeatureStyleOptions = {
        strokeColor: "#ff7859",
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeWeight: 3.0,
        fillColor: "#ff7859",
        fillOpacity: 1.0,
      };

      // Apply the style to a single boundary.
      //@ts-ignore
      featureLayer.style = (options: { feature: { placeId: string } }) => {
        if (options.feature.placeId == placeId) {
          return featureStyleOptions;
        }
      };
    };

  if (loadError) return <div>Error loading maps</div>;
  if (!isLoaded)
    return (
      <div className="flex h-full flex-col">
        <Jelly />
      </div>
    );

  return (
    <>
      <SearchComponent onSearch={handleSearch} />
      <div className="w-full">
        <GoogleMap
          mapContainerStyle={mapContainerStyle}
          zoom={originalZoom}
          center={mapCenter}
          onClick={showPin ? handleMapClick : () => {}}
          onLoad={(map) => {
            mapRef.current = map;
            setOriginalZoom(8);
          }}
          options={{
            disableDefaultUI: true,
            zoomControl: false,
            fullscreenControl: false,
            streetViewControl: false,
            mapId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_MAPS_MAP_ID!,
          }}
        >
          {selectedPin && <Marker position={selectedPin} />}
        </GoogleMap>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default ShowMap;
```

> I would be really happy if you can tell me why my initial code didn't work.

Thanks to my friend [Maruf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16321653/maruf-pulok?fbclid=IwAR0xu36usKNChjZpzOFULRsPaJYo15X7FQOvWf7OR2EKMUP1L2BPPQHtgiY) for helping me out.